# Error "Failed to open/read local data from file/application" when using CURL in GitHub Action to reference repository file

Tags: github, curl, github-actions

I have a GitHub action defined as follows.  It attempts to retrieve a file from my repo and post it to an external API via CURL, as follows:

```
name: "Publish API Reference to DeveloperHub"
on: [push]
jobs:
  deployment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Create/Update References
      run: |
          echo Starting Upload of Swagger
          curl --request POST \
            --verbose \
            --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
            --header "X-Api-Key: ${{secrets.DH_API_KEY}}" \
            --form "file=@Payments/Documentation/PaymentSOAP_Swagger.YAML" \
            --url "https://api.developerhub.io/api/v1/version/8973/reference"
          echo Done
```

It fails, however, with the message:

> curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

I have tried different variations of the `--form` argument, including:

- Omitting the quotes
- Omitting the "@"
- Substituting the absolute for the relative URL for the file to be posted.

But I still receive the same error.

What am I doing wrong?  What the proper way to do this - i.e. to use a GitHub Action to POST a file from my repository to an external API via CURL?

Please note, as well, that I have searched extensively online (including the official CURL and GitHub Actions documentation) for an answer to this, but have come up empty.  Although there is quite a but written about the error "Failed to open/read local data," nothing I've found addresses my particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  The main issue is that GitHub Actions cannot access repo files by default; you must do a checkout first!  I accomplished this by using the Bhacaz/checkout-files utility (courtesy of https://github.com/Bhacaz/checkout-files).

Below is my revised (working) Action code:

```
name: "Publish API Reference to DeveloperHub"
on: [push]
jobs:
  deployment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check Out Reference File
      uses: Bhacaz/checkout-files@v2
      with:
       files: Payments/Documentation/PaymentSOAP_Swagger.YAML
    - name: Create/Update References on DH
      run: |
          echo Starting Upload of Swagger
          curl --request POST \
            --verbose \
            --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
            --header "X-Api-Key: ${{secrets.DH_API_KEY}}" \
            --form "file=@Payments/Documentation/PaymentSOAP_Swagger.YAML" \
            --url "https://api.developerhub.io/api/v1/version/8973/reference"
          echo Done
```